# Piping a command directly to the shell executable

Tags: bash

I am trying to understand the difference between the following

Approach 1:

1. Launch a bash shell
2. On the bash shell type a command `my_command myargs`

Approach 2:

1. Launch a bash shell
2. Execute the following directly `my_command myargs | /bin/bash/`

My command passes in approach 1 but does not in approach 2. I was thinking both approaches were equivalent. Of course in approach 1 I have not done any commands/changed the path variables before doing my_command. In approach 2 I am just creating a brand new shell and piping my command into it.

Can someone explain the difference? Is it missing $PATH, environment variables etc? If so how can I echo/find out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "approach 2" pipes the **output** of `my_command` to bash.
It's equivalent to

```
$(my_command myargs)
```

If you instead pipe the *literal text*, it will work:

```
echo my_command myargs | /bin/bash/
```

Comment: Note that you may still see differences, since approach 1 uses an interactive shell and approach 2 does not. Typically, the only difference you might observe is if `my_command` is an alias or shell function, which may not be defined in non-interactive shells.